# Does the frequency of AC current affect the induced emf in a transformer (mutual induction)?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Faraday’s law states that the induced emf is directly proportional to the rate of change of flux.

So if I have a constant input voltage and increase the frequency of an alternating current in a transformer, would the rate of the secondary coil cutting field lines and thus the emf induced increase and if not, why?

I’m a bit confused by the word “rate”, and the idea of frequency affecting voltage seems really absurd to me.

Comment: When two coils are closely coupled, thinking in terms of just one coil will lead you astray.  Instead of one equation for one coil, you two *coupled* equations for the pair.

Comment: [Welcome to Physics.SE!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour) Note that you need to input _two_ line breaks to get a paragraph break in your post. The [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) also describes other formatting capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

> would the emf induced increase and if not, why?

When you have two coupled (ideal) inductors, you have to consider a coupled set of equations rather than one.

For example, and assuming sinusoidal excitation at angular frequency $\omega$, we can write

$$V_p = j\omega(L_p I_p + M I_s)$$
$$V_s = j\omega(M I_p + L_s I_s)$$

where $L_p, L_s, M$ are the primary, secondary, and mutual inductances respectively.

Consider the case that the secondary is open (not connected to a load) so that $I_s = 0$.  Then

$$V_p = j\omega L_p I_p$$
$$V_s = j\omega M I_p$$

and it follows that

$$V_s = j\omega M\frac{V_p}{j\omega L_p} = \frac{M}{L_p}V_p$$

The angular frequency dependence has canceled out!  In the case of unity coupling, (no flux leakage), we have that

$$M = \sqrt{L_p L_s}$$

and so

$$V_s = \sqrt{\frac{L_s}{L_p}}V_p$$

Since the inductances are proportional to the *square* of the number of turns $N$, we finally have the ideal transformer relation

$$V_s = \frac{N_s}{N_p}V_p$$

---

When the secondary *is* connected to a resistive load, Ohm's law yields

$$V_s = -R I_s$$

(The negative sign is there because we take $I_s$ to be positive if it is *in to* the more positive terminal of the secondary) and the second of the coupled equations becomes

$$-R I_s = j\omega(M I_p + L_s I_s) \Rightarrow I_s = -\frac{j\omega M}{R + j\omega L_s}I_p$$

Note that in the limit that $R \rightarrow 0$ and unity coupling, we get the ideal transformer relation

$$I_s = -\frac{N_p}{N_s}I_p$$

But for non-zero $R$, the secondary current *is* a function of the angular frequency $\omega$.  Once again, assuming unity coupling, we get

$$I_s =  -\frac{j\omega \frac{\sqrt{L_p L_s}}{R}}{1 + j\omega \frac{L_s}{R}}I_p$$

Note that as $\omega \rightarrow 0$, the secondary current goes to zero (for finite $L_p, L_s$) and so, there is no transformer action at DC.

On the other hand, for $\omega \gg \frac{R}{L_s}$, we recover the ideal transformer relation.

---

Having solved for $I_s$ in terms of $I_p$, we solve the first coupled equation for $V_p$ and get

$$V_p = \frac{j\omega L_p}{1+j\omega\frac{L_s}{R}}I_p$$

Again, note that as $\omega \rightarrow 0$, we have

$$V_p \rightarrow j\omega L_p I_p$$

and see that there is no transformer action at DC, i.e., the primary doesn't 'see' the resistance attached to the secondary.

Also, for $\omega \gg \frac{R}{L_s}$, we have

$$V_p \approx \left(\frac{N_p}{N_s}\right)^2R\,I_p$$

which is the ideal transformer relation for the transformation of impedances.

---

Finally, note that in the dual limit as $L_p, L_s \rightarrow \infty$, keeping the ratio $\frac{L_p}{L_s} = \frac{N_p}{N_s}$ constant, the ideal transformer equations become exact over all $\omega$, i.e., the ideal transformer 'works at DC'.